# Passing Parameters to a method using delegates

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

Suppose I have a simple method like this

```
class Program
{
    public static void show(string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

Now I have a delegate which will refer to this method

```
Action<string> Del = Program.show;
```

Suppose I have to pass some name say "Jack" to the method. how do I do that using delegates? I need the syntax for that.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either call it like

```cs
Del("Jack");
```

or

```cs
Del.Invoke("Jack");
```

Both will do essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

```
Del.Invoke("Jack");
```

or

```
Del("Jack");
```